# Attempting to Install PyQT5 for PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm going to File > Settings > Project: {project name} > Python Interpreter > then adding the PyQt5 package.

It's resulting in an error stating the following,

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/mistotic/Documents/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/mistotic/Documents/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/mistotic/Documents/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/c_/s7gtqr3j15x7cxvktp3g3zqw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-754af7_z/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/c_/s7gtqr3j15x7cxvktp3g3zqw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-754af7_z/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/private/var/folders/c_/s7gtqr3j15x7cxvktp3g3zqw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-754af7_z/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/c_/s7gtqr3j15x7cxvktp3g3zqw0000gn/T/pip-install-k7dhkaq6/pyqt5_0b195843befd40e487ae8516705cb7f2/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/c_/s7gtqr3j15x7cxvktp3g3zqw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-754af7_z/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/c_/s7gtqr3j15x7cxvktp3g3zqw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-754af7_z/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/c_/s7gtqr3j15x7cxvktp3g3zqw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-754af7_z/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Any assistance in what this means is appreciated. :)

Tried installing via pip and it wasn't being recognized so I attempted via the IDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3+, You can simply install using pip3 install PyQT5 otherwise try to download the package and place it under sit-packages(for python 2 versions)